# T-SQL accessing next/previous row of a table

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-view, row-number

`UPDATE:` I figured this out soon after posting this ... Essentially I used `ROW_NUMBER` to created sub-partitions of TaskAssignments based on TaskId `ORDER BY` TaskAssigmentId`. Thanks guys.

Suppose I build a system to keep track of simple task assignments with the following schema:

```
Tasks:
TaskId           CurrentlyAssignedTo TaskAddedTime              TaskEndTime
A                FooBar              2013-05-03 23:28:32.060    2013-05-07 10:12:32.060
B                Bob                 2013-05-03 20:12:32.060    NULL

TaskAssignments:
TaskAssignmentId TaskId AssignedTo  StartTime
1                A      Foo         2013-05-03 23:28:32.060
2                A      Bar         2013-05-04 20:12:32.060
3                A      FooBar      2013-05-05 10:12:32.060
4                B      Alice       2013-05-03 20:12:32.060
5                B      Bob         2013-05-06 10:12:32.060
```

Table `Tasks` contains the current information of tasks. A particular task (A or B) could be assigned to multiple workers (one at a time). Every time an assignment happens (including creation time), an entry is added to `TaskAssignments` table specifying to whom the task was assigned and at what time. When a task is reassigned, `CurrentlyAssignedTo` field in `Tasks` is updated with the current worker. When a task is fully completed, `TaskEndTime` field is updated in `Tasks` table. `TaskAssignmentId` is an incremental index.

With that, I want to build a query/view to output something like this:

```
VwTaskBreakDown:
TaskId    AssignedTo    StartTime                 EndTime
A         Foo           2013-05-03 23:28:32.060   2013-05-04 20:12:32.060
A         Bar           2013-05-04 20:12:32.060   2013-05-05 10:12:32.060
A         FooBar        2013-05-05 10:12:32.060   2013-05-07 10:12:32.060
B         Alice         2013-05-03 20:12:32.060   2013-05-06 10:12:32.060
B         Bob           2013-05-06 10:12:32.060   NULL
```

Where, for a particular task, the `EndTime` of an assignment is the `StartTime` of the next assignment. If there is no next assignment, the `EndTime` comes from `TaskEndTime` of table `Tasks`.

Any hint into how this can be done nicely?

`Disclaimer`: I don't have any prior experience with SQL

Thanks,
Noobie

Answer (score 0):

You Can Try like this...

```
Select TaskId,AssignedTo,StartTime,cOALESCE(
  (sELECT MIN(StartTime) FROM tABLENAME
A WHERE A.TaskId=t.TaskId AND a.StartTime>t.StartTime),
  (sELECT TaskEndTime FROM T1 B WHERE B.TaskId=T.TaskId AND B.CurrentlyAssignedTo=T.AssignedTo)
)AS eNDtIME
FROM tABLEnAME
T
```

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e0332/5)